# Why am I contunially getting the "798" message?

Tags: vpn, azure, gateway

Right, so I'm attempting to install a Point-to-Site VPN on a second laptop - after having successfully installed this on my desktop. I have;

- created a second root certificate key,
- Installed the Client Certification on the Laptop
- I have followed the instructions below:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-files-samples/tree/master/point-to-site-vpn-azure-files

So why can't I still connect to my VPN? I'm getting really impatient with Azure products right now, if I follow a set of instructions, I expect a product to work in the way in which the instructions say it'll work.

Anyone else had these issues, and now did you overcome this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try a couple things.

1. Make sure the certificate is located in the [user store](https://www.systemsup.co.uk/azure-point-to-site-error-798/) on client machine2 and not the computer store.
2. Try the working client cert from machine1 on machine2.  If the cert from machine1 works on machine2 there is something wrong with your key pair.